# Do mobile AMD A8 processors support IOMMU/VT-D PCI Passthrough for virtual machines?

Tags: laptop, hardware-virtualization

I have been looking at laptops lately, and I was wondering if the laptop AMD A8 CPUs support PCI passthrough in Xen Hypervisor or KVM. If they do, which specific CPU model numbers are known to support PCI Passthrough?

Note, I would look at Intel, however A. Intel is too expensive, and B. all the laptops that aren't ultra expensive do not support VT-D.

Answer (score 5):

IOMMU/VT-D is available in pretty much all AMD CPUs.  The gotcha is if it is implemented on the motherboard.

edit:

Note the Wikipedia article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOMMU

> I/O virtualization is not performed by the CPU, but instead by the chipset.